# How to quantitively compare two seismic waveform data?

Tags: seismology, seismic, spectral-analysis

Our group has built an Arduino-based device with an MPU6050 to act as our seismometer for our project, with the data being displayed on Amaseis. Our proctor demands that we quantitively assess its "effectiveness" through factors that we determined. We decided it is evaluated based on (this is subject to change depending on the answers to this question) proximity,  effective range, and accuracy.

Please, how do we determine the proximity, effective range, and accuracy of our project, and what statistical tool (as it is required to use one) do we need in order to do so?

***Note***: For accuracy, we've been planning to go to our local seismological institution (PHILVOLCS) to obtain waveform data, and we ought to compare it to our data. Although, this raises many questions such as:

How do we quantitively compare two seismic data for accuracy, if they are taken from different locations? (and most probably different timeframes)

As it is probably obvious, we are very unknowledgeable in this subject, and we would VERY much appreciate any help, feedback, or recommendation. As junior high students, we are very lost on how to proceed with this now.

Comment: I would argue that the effectiveness of your sensor is related primarily to sensitivity and frequency response. From my understanding, seismic sensors measure amplitudes from 0.1 m to 1 picometer at a range of frequecies from 10 Hz to 1 miliHertz. So determining what the specifications for your sensor are is important before trying to compare waveforms to another sensor